# is there a difference between flask-jwt and flask-jwt-extended?

Tags: flask-jwt, flask-jwt-extended

I just learned about flask and JWT like a week ago so I could really use some help.
Can someone explain the difference between flask-jwt and flask-jwt-extended?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Flask-JWT does not have as many features, has made some silly design choices, and has been abandoned for years (look at how many [open pull requests](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-jwt/pulls) there are on the github page). Flask-JWT-Extended has more features, is better documented, and is still actively maintained. If you are looking for a JWT extension for Flask, you should absolutely use Flask-JWT-Extended over Flask-JWT.

Comment: thanks for this concise answer, you saved me a lot of time ^_^

Comment: yet do you have any tutorial, guide or tips on how to implement them with templates rendering?
 I'm trying to use them here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55296439/implementing-flask-jwt-extended-with-templates-rendering) but I'm struggeling

Answer (score 0):

Flask-JWT-Extended works pretty much similar way to Flask-JWT, In addition to which there are a lots of functionalities that it extends such as token refresh.

Also from Python 3.10, the support for flask-jwt has been removed.