# How to authenticate with flask-restful using class Resource?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-jwt-extended

I am building flask rest and planning to use flask-restful. I am familiar with flask login, but understand that with restful I need jwt.How to implement authentication? with flask-jwt or flask-jwt-extended? Also I am not using blueprints for this small project.I need to authenticate my routes(that are actually class Resource).
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the commits on the Github pages of both [Flask-JWT](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-jwt/commits) and [Flask-JWT-Extended](https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/commits), I believe it's safe to say that Flask-JWT was abandoned. I would advise to go for Flask-JWT-Extended, it also has more features (like refresh tokens).

Also mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55118765/is-there-a-difference-between-flask-jwt-and-flask-jwt-extended).